# How to Store "direct link" to an image using Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I need to access an image stored on Firebase Storage by a direct link, eg

```
http://myfirebasehost.com/storage/imgIwant.png
```

For all I know, it can only this type of URL using the protocol `gs://`, however, it is not accessible by link, only in the SDK api.

I need a solution exactly as described above using the Firebase platform, if not possible, accept other suggestions.

My code has constants that are links to images. It turns out that if I want to update this picture, I have to make a new deployment. Instead I want to update the image at the same URL. It would be impossible to do this with the firebase (to my knowledge) because the URL provided by Storage is not accessible by link.

Another alternative might be to convert an image to base64 and stored in the database, but would be very extensive and impractical.

Comment: You seem to have a problem getting your code to work. The best way to get help with that on Stack Overflow is to [reproduce the problem in a minimal amount of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that code here.

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423890/is-there-a-way-to-overwrite-a-saved-file-in-firebase-storage/62073071#62073071

Answer (score 26):

How to translate your `gs storage location` to a `direct url` by example:

`gs://nobs-f32f2.appspot.com/profile/1s_by_wlop-dc1sdan.jpg`

becomes

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nobs-f32f2.appspot.com/o/profile%2F1s_by_wlop-dc1sdan.jpg?alt=media`

`1st` be sure to URL escape your blob path. For example, swap forward slashes (`/`) for %2F and spaces () for %20.

`2nd` be sure you've open read access where needed. Here is an open rule to get moving:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think the URL would work when missing the "token" parameter in the query string. Yet, I just tried it and no problem.  +1

Comment: Is it possible to not have the ?alt=media ?

Comment: @Roberto OOC, do the firebase storage security rules still work? or does anyone with the link have access to the file? If security yes, how is the heck is the auth being handled?? lol

Comment: Rules always run - no magic backdoor links if that is your thinking.  If you don't provide a valid token, `request.auth` will be null. In the open rule set above, `allow read: if true` means everything passes for reads, including tokenless requests.

Answer (score 20):

With Firebase Storage, you're given two URLs that you can use to represent files:

```
// "Private" internal URL, only accessible through Firebase Storage API
// This is protected by Firebase Storage Security Rules & Firebase Auth
gs://bucket/object

// "Public" unguessable URL, accessible by anyone with the link
// This is secured because that token is *very* hard for someone to guess
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object?alt=media&token=<token>
```

The first option requires that you use the `reference.getDownloadURL()` method to convert the internal `gs://` URL into a public `https://` URL.

The second option allows you to share this public but unguessable URL with trusted individuals, and allows them to access content without authentication to Firebase or using your app--think sharing family photos with Google Photos. Likely this behavior will be good enough, unless you desire public sharing with clean URLs. You can use this URL in a browser, or use any other HTTP library to download it. We provide the ability to download these files as well (off a reference), so you don't need to get a third party library, you can just use us.

I strongly recommend reading [our docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) for more information on this.

Comment: If you would like to share this link to the graph API with link=downloadURL, facebook logs the error: error link should represent a valid URL.

Comment: Does the token ever change? I'd like to save the full URL in the database associated with an object and use it later. (without using getDownloadUrl on a child)

Comment: @m1crdy I'm willing to bet that this is because you're not properly URL encoding the firebase storage URL when you send it to Facebook.

Comment: @DoruChidean the token changes when you overwrite the file, or if you invalidate the token in the web console.

Comment: From backend perspective this answer is not useful. The mobile users don't have secure way to access the firebase store (except if they have account). So I have to create them download url , but there is not such method in the python Admin API or such REST functionality. So firebase give me no choice but to give public access (and I don't want to), or to have service that downloads the image through the backend using Google cloud storage and not firebase storage. So looks to me like the backend APIs or the admin API, is last concern, targeting mostly mobile users making firebase escape hard.

Comment: @makkasi if you're on the server, you can use the Cloud Storage Client Libraries (e.g. python: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) and generate a signed URL. That can be directly downloaded on the client and doesn't require making the file public.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I can't because Google are not supporting their own library google-cloud-python on Google App engine. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893

Comment: It does not generate two different URL.It basically returns the same URL which is in Firebase Storage

Comment: why token is needed when I can directly access the file from `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object?alt=media` ?

Comment: If you're accessing it directly that means it's public. The point of the token is to make it private, so only those with the token can access it.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I don't understand. You say '"Public" unguessable URL, accessible by anyone with the link. This is secured because that token is *very* hard for someone to guess.'. But... If link works even without a token, then link isn't unguessable anymore. You don't need to guess a token. You need to guess only bucket and object name. Or the token is not required only if you make the object allowed to read by anyone like in [fionbio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428634/758991)?

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko correct, if your read rules allow public read access you don't need a token. Obviously, we don't recommend public read access to objects unless they truly are public. It's easy to use read:false globally and only generate sharable URLs if that's how you want to use the app, though we recommend using Security Rules for more control over access.

Comment: Is there a "I could careless about security, just give me a public link I can use on all images for my bucket with out running getdownloadurl option"?

Comment: @FabricioG if you're dead set on this you can set the security rules to public and just use the `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{bucket}/o/path/to/file` and it should work

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!!  I'm a little surprised to not find that much info on this tip.  I realize the firebase way is to programmatically get the download link but in a web environment you just slap the images in a public folder and can href them.  @MikeMcDonald

Comment: Because if you're hosting public, static content you should just upload it to [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) and serve it from there rather than upload to a GCS bucket and then pull it in.

Answer (score 9):

Year 2020, I had quite a hard time figuring this out, especially because of the limitations of the `CharacterSet` in Swift for encoding a String (or most probably I'm missing something).

Here are the steps how I managed to convert a "path" (folder path) of a Blob on Firebase Storage (after upload).

1. Given a storage metadata after upload, (in iOS, we have the class called `FIRStorageMetadata`.) get the string objects called `path` and `bucket`.
2. Encode properly the path string! This is important! If you miss a character, obviously you'll get an error when you attempt to download the complete direct URL.

   - In iOS, I encode the path string using the CharacterSet `urlHostAllowed`. BUT, this is not enough, like I said in the above, it is either there is no CharacterSet that encodes a string into a URL including the **"+'** plus sign. 
     So after encoding using the `urlHostAllowed`, I call replace occurrence string method, replace **"+"** with **"%2B"**
   - One way to test if you are encoding the path string correctly is to compare your encoding result with the one you can get from the Firebase Storage UI.
3. Concatenate the strings:

   - "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/"
   - bucket object
   - "/o/"
   - correctly encoded path object.
   - "?alt=media"

Voila!

**FAQs**

1. Can we omit the **token**? Yes, certainly. It just works. Been doing it ever since I learned it.
2. Can we omit the `?alt=media`? Nope! You'll just get a string in json format and not the file.

Answer (score 8):

For those who just want to get a link

In `console > Storage`

Select a specific photo and you will see the link below.
[image]

Comment: this no longer seems to apply?

Comment: It works like this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/694

Answer (score 4):

To convert into a public URL check example.

Suppose the link is gs://funzone-website.appspot.com/public/logo.jpg

let g=funzone-website.appspot.com/public/logo.jpg

replace file path with % if there is a folder. In the above example, the public is a folder, add ?alt=media and add o.

Now g=funzone-website.appspot.com/o/public%2Flogo.jpg?alt=media

convert and replace path(/) with %2F

To convert this use [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{g}](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%7Bg%7D)

or

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funzone-website.appspot.com/o/public%2Flogo.jpg?alt=media

If there is no folder(public) then the link is

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funzone-website.appspot.com/o/logo.jpg?alt=media

Comment: it worked, but we must set rules to the specific folder to true, ie no authendications otherwise it throws error

Answer (score 2):

***2020***

**Firebase is connected to Google Cloud Platform:**

You need to make the bucket or the desired objects public on Google Cloud Platform and there you will get a simple link without any need to edit it:

[Making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)

You can also use the link without making the data public (but then you will have to be signed in to access) :

Go to [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com) > select your project > Storage > Browser > Open bucket appID.appspot.com > open any object and there you have both uri (that Firebase console provides) and the URL.

- I tried all the given methods here but they don't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Another option is an URL of the format:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/PROJECT-ID/FILEPATH
```

`PROJECT-ID`: project ID of Firebase project

`FILEPATH`: path to project file

Answer (score 0):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow  write: if request.auth != null;
      allow  read: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

You can try this because it allow public read access

Answer (score 0):

If your want your images to be public -

Add this to your storage rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow  write: if request.auth != null;
      allow  read: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like

```
export const getMedia = (folderId, mediaId) =>`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}/o/${folderId}%2F${mediaId}?alt=media`;
```