# Is there a way to overwrite a saved file in firebase storage?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I am dealing with profile pictures in my ionic 1 App. I am searching for a way to update a file in firebase storage such that the download link remains the same.
Is it possible or any other way to achieve the required?

Answer (score 3):

You can't update the file and maintain the same public download link--it's a different file, so it's assumed that you might want to change the access permissions

Just re-fetch the URL and download the file once it's been updated (it's actually returned in the metadata returned on upload, so you can send it to other apps right after you change it, no need to grab the URL separately):

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  var url = snapshot.downloadURL;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer says, basically you cant update the image without it changing the permissions.

BUT, if you change your rules for the path where your image is stored to say

```
allow read: if true;
allow write: if request.auth != null;
```

this basically makes it where anyone with the link can see the image. This will let you see the new image from the old download link.

But just know that this also means anybody with this link can see the image, not just people from your app.

Answer (score 3):

Hey so I was dealing with something similar recently. According to the docs there isn't a direct way to overwrite an existing file but I did find a way to do this and retrieve a new url. Here is how I store and update.

```
const storeFile = async (file) => {
    const ref = firebase.firestore.collection('bin').doc();
    const id = ref.id;
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('bin/' + id)
    await storageRef.put(file)
}

const updateFile = async (id, file) => {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/path').child(id);
    // Put the new file in the same child ref.
    await storageRef.put(file);
    // Get the new URL
    const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
}
```

Comment: What is `id` here?

Comment: @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson Usually I will store the file under a unique id. I'll either create an id in firestore, or use a uuid generator. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

File update should be made on https://console.cloud.google.com/storage and after replacing the file with same name, then it's metadata should be updated with the *firebaseStorageDownloadTokens* key and previously used token.